# Copy all text from word document to antoher word document without formating

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to copy all the text from the active Word document (docx) into another new Word document (docx), the thing is that in the original word document I got a lot of formatting and I just need the raw text !

I've try to do something but I'm kinda loss... :

```
Sub extract_text()

    Dim originalDoc As Document, targetDocAs Document,
    Dim myPath As String, myPath1 As String, myPath2 As String
    Dim rng As Range

    myPath = ThisDocument.Path
    myPath1 = myPath & "\1.docx"
    

    Set originalDoc = Documents.Open(myPath)
    Set targetDoc= Documents.Open(myPath1)

    originalDoc.Content.Copy
    Set rng = targetDoc.Content
    rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    rng.Paste

    targetDoc.SaveAs myPath2

    originalDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    targetDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

Could you help me ?

Comment: `rng.PasteSpecial Datatype:=wdPasteText`

Answer (score 1):

You really need to learn to use the Object Browser and the macro recorder. You would have got the answer to this in less time than it took to post your question.
Use [`PasteAndFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.pasteandformat).

```
rng.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
```